# I am getting data and empty cells while importing an excel sheet

Tags: php, excel, laravel

I am trying to import an excel sheet.I am getting data but i am also getting empty cells with it.I have tried other options but its not working.
I am using following code :

```
 $path = Input::file('file')->getRealPath();
                $data = Excel::load($path, function($reader) {
                })->get();
```

Can anyone please help me to solve this.I am not able to move ahead.Thanks in advance.